# Are brand-new DNS registrations an easy way to detect phishing?

Tags: dns, phishing

Today I received an SMS

> AusPost: Your package address is incorrect and delivery failed, please
> update address information via the link.
> `https://auspost.requestupdate.com`

If I do a `whois auspost.requestupdate.com`  by https://www.whois.com/whois/auspost.requestupdate.com I get nothing. It either gives me auspost.com or requestupdate.com. This seems to vary based on history

However `whois requestupdate.com`  gives

```
    Registered On: 2022-08-17
    Expires On: 2023-08-17
    Updated On: 2022-08-17
```

So I was thinking that this is a pretty obvious phishing attempt  - is that correct or am I missing something?

I also got the following

```
    Name Servers: ns1.nnaab.co, ns2.nnaab.co
```

Whois of nnaab.co gives

```
    Registrar: NameSilo, LLC
    Registered On: 2022-07-06
    Expires On: 2023-07-06
    Updated On: 2022-08-05
```

It all seems too easy to see how suspicious this is due to the DNS ages associated with TELSTRA - is that correct or am I missing something?

Is there anything automatic which detects this age-type signature and can take an action, such as telling a firewall/IPS that this DNS query, and hence IP address, is to a known-bad address?

Answer (score 4):

> If I do a whois auspost.requestupdate.com ... I get nothing

Because this is a subdomain. These are not included in whois. Only the primary domains (i.e. requestupdate.com) are.

> However whois requestupdate.com gives ... Registered On: 2022-08-17 ... So I was thinking that this is a pretty obvious phishing attempt ...

History of domain registration is a feature is often used together with other features in computing a domain reputation, but it is not a reliable indicator by its own.

Issues in setting up and maintaining domains for example might allow an attacker to misuse or create subdomains of an established domain with high reputation - see  [subdomain takeover](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Subdomain_takeovers). Also attackers regularly compromise existing hosting and use it for phishing - often keeping the site as it is intact but controlling specific URL path or subdomains.

And some companies like to create new domains for campaigns, so treating any new domain as malicious is not true either. But it is good to be suspicious in this case.

Answer (score 4):

There are many firewalls and URL filtering solutions that will take domain age into account and either block the request or show a warning before passing the request through. The ones I've seen look for <30 days as a red flag since malicious domains tend to do their bad things shortly after being created, and by then, the domain gains a reputation score that can be used more reliably than age alone.

But domain age, even for established companies, is not a complete picture of suspicion. Some companies set up new domains for new services, new ad campaigns, etc. You can't make a definitive analysis based on age alone. Age is a ***factor*** that is taken into account.

- age
- random-looking string as the domain name
- SPF/DKIM/DMARC records
- IP geolocation
- hosting location

A brand-new domain, that is a random string, with no other DNS records, hosted on EC2, is pretty suspicious.

A brand-new domain, that has actual brand words, with full SPF/DKIM/DMARC records, a public whois, and is hosted in an IP range belonging to a non-hosting company IP block is not as suspicious.

Nothing in cyber security is binary. Things come together as factors for suspicion and for security. There is no silver bullet.